# Is it possible to truly hide a url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a url that is

```
filemgr.php
```

when a user navigates to lower levels of said file manager it shows up as

```
filemgr.php#userfiles/username/Images
```

Is there a way to just have it show up as

```
filemgr.php
```

with out the rest of the url showing?

I am open to .htaccess editing and php code.

This Jquery is being used to show sublevels:

```
function renderFileRow(data) {

    var $link = $('<a class="name" />')
    .attr('href', data.is_dir ? '#' + data.path : './'+data.path)
    .text(data.name);
    var $dl_link = $('<a/>').attr('href','?do=download&file='+encodeURIComponent(data.path))
    .addClass('download').text('download');
    var $delete_link = $('<a href="#" />').attr('data-file',data.path).addClass('delete').text('delete');
    var perms = [];
    if(data.is_readable) perms.push('read');
    if(data.is_writable) perms.push('write');
    if(data.is_executable) perms.push('exec');
    var $html = $('<tr />')
    .addClass(data.is_dir ? 'is_dir' : '')
    .append( $('<td class="first" />').append($link) )
    .append( $('<td/>').attr('data-sort',data.is_dir ? -1 : data.size)
    .html($('<span class="size" />').text(formatFileSize(data.size))) )
    .append( $('<td/>').attr('data-sort',data.mtime).text(formatTimestamp(data.mtime)) )
    .append( $('<td/>').text(perms.join('+')) )
    .append( $('<td/>').append($dl_link).append( data.is_deleteable ? $delete_link : '') )
    return $html;

}
```

here is the PHP code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'en_US.UTF-8');

$tmp = realpath($_REQUEST['file']);
if($tmp === false)
err(404,'File or Directory Not Found');
if(substr($tmp, 0,strlen(__DIR__)) !== __DIR__)
err(403,"Forbidden");

if(!$_COOKIE['_sfm_xsrf'])
setcookie('_sfm_xsrf',bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16)));
if($_POST) {
if($_COOKIE['_sfm_xsrf'] !== $_POST['xsrf'] || !$_POST['xsrf'])
err(403,"XSRF Failure");
}
$file = $_REQUEST['file'] ?: './userfiles/'.htmlentities($_SESSION['username']);



if($_GET['do'] == 'list') {
if (is_dir($file)) {
$directory = $file;
$result = array();
$files = array_diff(scandir($directory), array('.','..'));
foreach($files as $entry) if($entry !== basename(__FILE__)) {
     $i = $directory . '/' . $entry;
$stat = stat($i);
$result[] = array(
'mtime' => $stat['mtime'],
'size' => $stat['size'],
'name' => basename($i),
'path' => preg_replace('@^\./@', '', $i),
'is_dir' => is_dir($i),
'is_deleteable' => (!is_dir($i) && is_writable($directory)) ||
(is_dir($i) && is_writable($directory) && is_recursively_deleteable($i)),
'is_readable' => is_readable($i),
'is_writable' => is_writable($i),
'is_executable' => is_executable($i),
);
}
} else {
err(412,"Not a Directory");
}
echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'is_writable' => is_writable($file), 'results' =>$result));
exit;
} elseif ($_POST['do'] == 'delete') {
rmrf($file);
exit;
} elseif ($_POST['do'] == 'mkdir') {
chdir($file);
@mkdir($_POST['name']);
exit;
} elseif ($_POST['do'] == 'upload') {
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_FILES);
var_dump($_FILES['file_data']['tmp_name']);
var_dump(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_data']['tmp_name'], $file.'/'.$_FILES['file_data']['name']));
exit;
} elseif ($_GET['do'] == 'download') {
$filename = basename($file);
header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($file));
header('Content-Length: '. filesize($file));
header(sprintf('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%s',
strpos('MSIE',$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? rawurlencode($filename) : "\"$filename\"" ));
ob_flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
}
function rmrf($dir) {
if(is_dir($dir)) {
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..'));
foreach ($files as $file)
rmrf("$dir/$file");
rmdir($dir);
} else {
unlink($dir);
}
}
function is_recursively_deleteable($d) {
$stack = array($d);
while($dir = array_pop($stack)) {
if(!is_readable($dir) || !is_writable($dir))
return false;
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..'));
foreach($files as $file) if(is_dir($file)) {
$stack[] = "$dir/$file";
}
    }
    return true;
    }

    function err($code,$msg) {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => array('code'=>intval($code), 'msg' => $msg)));
    exit;
    }

    function asBytes($ini_v) {
    $ini_v = trim($ini_v);
    $s = array('g'=> 1<<30, 'm' => 1<<20, 'k' => 1<<10);
    return intval($ini_v) * ($s[strtolower(substr($ini_v,-1))] ?: 1);
    }

    $MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE = min(asBytes(ini_get('post_max_size')), asBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize')));
```

Comment: How's your application generate `#userfiles/username/Images` this url?

Comment: `$file = $_REQUEST['file'] ?: './userfiles/'.htmlentities($_SESSION['username']).'/';` I need it there so each user can only access their own file manager.

Comment: Do you really mean anchor-tag (#) or is it a typo?

Comment: Also, it is being done by jquery when you want to go to sub levels

Comment: the `#` is fine. I just dont want the rest of the url to show.

Comment: see above for Jquery for render file row

Comment: Store the rest in a cookie. Although you don't want to do this. It's asking for side effects. Why would you want to hide this at all? Fooling the user?

Comment: I thought its ajax that generates the URL but your script not even requesting to the server for the `#userfiles/username/Images` url so you can't do that with .htaccess though. You have to do this in client end with your current script.

Comment: I have same question as GolezTrol - why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to hide it so they cannot change the username path to another users folders.  example `#userfiles/ABC1/` and then in the url it can be changed to `#userfiles/ABC2/...` they can then see the other users files...

Comment: You'll want to use a different method then hiding the url to protect user files. Such as check if they are logged in as that user before showing the files.

Comment: It only happens when a user clicks on sub-folders that the URL is changed.  I just don't want to the show at all.

Comment: @Andrew, you said to test for logged in user, I have tired that, On line 15 of the above edit, I would like to add the condition, but have been unsuccessful.  can you please explain what kind of condition i should set or test for.

Answer (score 2):

One solution, rather than hiding the url through htaccess or some other means, is to do a 1 page site. When a user clicks a link, the files are simply `included` into the current page, and/or the page is modified with AJAX, so that the user never leaves the page, and the URL never changes.

For example, if someone clicks a link "Show me my images", that link is a jquery button, that runs a `$.get` function, which grabs the images, and displays them on the page, without ever leaving the page.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: By doing a `php include'file_mgr_php.php` at the top should fix this then?

Comment: Don't know your website architecture, but I don't think that is what I suggested, made an edit to answer.

Comment: ahh gotya...let me play around with this, and see if i can get it!

thanks for this!